# How to 'use' a module, but omit one function?

Tags: elixir

I have two modules, that I both need to 'use', but they both define a `trace/3` function. How can I use them both without getting the 'conflicts with local function' error? `except` does not work.

I do not use the trace function.

Note: this concerns the `Phoenix.ConnCase` and the `Tesla` modules.

Comment: `use Tesla, except: [:trace]` should work based on a quick read of https://github.com/teamon/tesla/blob/master/lib/tesla.ex#L198.

Comment: Right. I did not intuitively grasp that options to the 'use' command are handled by the module you're using, where options to 'alias' for example are handled by the alias macro.

Comment: Options to `use` macro are evidently handled by [`Kernel.use/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#use/2) macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no general way to do this with `use`. The module needs to explicitly support exclusion of imported functions. `Phoenix.ConnTest` (`use`d by `MyApp.ConnCase`) does not seem to support `except`, [but Tesla does](https://github.com/teamon/tesla/blob/f7fea9cc86173d23616e4896b46349b2d1ec823c/lib/tesla.ex#L198), which should solve your problem. Just add `except: [:trace]` to `use Tesla`:

```
use Tesla, except: [:trace]
```